# JavaScript, Bootstrap selectpicker, keep values on select when other changes

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want persist the 2nd selected options when the first one changes. I've made a jsfiddle to work with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/yeh6b83s/40/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // I'll give and empty array, because I will assume that at first is has no data on database
    let values = [];
    if(1 /* Originally here are some js conditions*/) {
        getAL1ByCountry(values);
    } 
    $('#adm_l_1').on('change', function() {
      getAL3ByAL1(values);
    });
    $('#adm_l_1').change();
});

// This functions works with ajax but now I'm just giving some arrays of objects to make the example    
function getAL1ByCountry(value) {
  let data = {'data': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Chile'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'USA'}]};
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data.data, function (k, v) {
    console.log(v);
    var _selected = false;
    $.each(value, function (k2, v2) {
      if (v2.id == v.id) _selected = true;
    });

    if (_selected)
      $('#adm_l_1').append('<option value="' + v.id + '" selected>' + v.name + '</option>');
    else
      $('#adm_l_1').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
  });
  $('#adm_l_1').selectpicker('refresh');

  $('#adm_l_1').change();
}

function getAL3ByAL1(values) {
  $('#adm_l_3').empty();
  // Now I will assume that an ajax call was succes and it gives me this data:
  /*$.ajax({
                  url: '/getAL1ByCountry',
                  method: 'POST',
                  data: {
                      country   : country_id
                  }
              }).done(function (data) {
        */
  let data = {
    'data': [
      {'id': 1, 'name': 'A'},
      {'id': 2, 'name': 'B'},
      {'id': 3, 'name': 'C'},
      {'id': 4, 'name': 'D'},
      {'id': 5, 'name': 'E'},
    ]
  };
  $.each(data.data, function (k, v) {
    console.log('data', data);
    var _selected = false;
    $.each(values, function (k2, v2) {
      if (v2 == v.id) _selected = true;
    });
    if (_selected)
      $('#adm_l_3').append('<option value="' + v.id + '" selected>' + v.name + '</option>');
    else
      $('#adm_l_3').append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
  });
  $('#adm_l_3').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

My second select change the values from the first one. In the example that's not clear, but the idea is that:

"if I change the values from the first select, don't remove the values from the 2nd one"

There's and `empty()` method necesary for this library, because without it it will load this situation each time an option is picked:

(If I pick A)
A
(If I pick B)
AAB
(If I pick C)
AABABC

etc

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your issue is with the following part :

```
$.each(values, function (k2, v2) {
    if (v2.id == v.id) _selected = true;
}
```

`values` is always empty and is never feed.
So you can save the current value of your select in a temp variable like this :

```
let saved = $('#adm_l_3').val();
```

And rework your algo to use this instead of `values`.

```
$.each(data.data, function (k, v) {
    var _selected = v.id == saved;

    if (_selected)
        /* your code */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vksw8e9t/6/

Comment: This way the data for 2nd select will not bu updated

Comment: @pmiranda You want to be able to update the 2nd select data without changing the value selected ?

Comment: Yes. each "country" will add options to the 2nd select. Each country calls to ajax, and brings new data to the 2nd select. So I don't want to lose the selected options of the 2nd select after each ajax call

Comment: @pmiranda But what if the first country give you the options "A - B - C" and second country gives you "D - E - F" ?
What is your expected behavior here ?

Comment: A,B,C,D,E,F <-- they all together. The values that I compare are the selected options stored in the database. I make a foreach to compare those: the stored on db and all the values selecetd from the DOM

Comment: @pmiranda I've edited my answer. Should work as you want it now :)